Jest Testing: Difficulty Mocking Functions Across Files
I'm trying to write tests for the CreateVendor function using Jest and Supertest. I'm stuck on how to mock the dependencies (generateSalt, hashPassword) to properly test the function's behavior. I'm getting this error: "Property generateSalt does not exist in the provided object.
This concise statement should effectively explain your difficulty and provide context for your mentor to assist you.
Controller function
export const CreateVendor = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { address, email, foodType, name, ownerName, password, phone, pincode } = <CreateVendorInput>req.body
    try {
        const findOne = await findVendor('', email)
        if (!findOne) {
            const bcryptSalt = await generateSalt()
            const bcryptPassword = await hashPassword(password, bcryptSalt)
            const CreateVendor = await Vendor.create({
                name: name,
                email: email,
                address: address,
                foodType: foodType,
                ownerName: ownerName,
                password: bcryptPassword,
                phone: phone,
                pincode: pincode,
                salt: bcryptSalt,
                rating: 0,
                serviceAvailable: false,
                coverImage: [],
            })
            return res.status(201).json({ "success": CreateVendor })
        } else {
            throw new BadRequestError('Vendor Already Exists', 'Admin/CreateVendor')
        }
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
}

Test file
it('creates a new vendor successfully', async () => {
            //@ts-ignore
            const mockVendorData: CreateVendorInput = test_data.vendor
            // const mockSalt = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('mockedSalt'); // Replace with a sample salt string
            // const mockHashedPassword = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('hashedPassword123');

            //@ts-ignore
            jest.spyOn(Vendor, 'create').mockResolvedValueOnce(mockVendorData)
            //@ts-ignore
            jest.spyOn(Vendor, 'find').mockResolvedValueOnce(null)
            // jest.mocked(generateSalt).mockImplementation(mockSalt);
            // jest.mocked(hashPassword).mockImplementation(mockHashedPassword);


            const res = await supertest(app)
                .post('/admin/vendor') // Adjust path if necessary
                .send(mockVendorData)
                .expect(201); // Expect successful creation status code
            console.log(res.body)
            expect(res.body.success).toHaveProperty('name', mockVendorData.name); // Check name in response
            expect(res.body.success).toHaveProperty('email', mockVendorData.email);
        }, 50000);

Error
CreateVendor function
    × creates a new vendor successfully (10063 ms)

  ● CreateVendor function › creates a new vendor successfully

    expected 201 "Created", got 404 "Not Found"

      91 |                 .post('/admin/vendor') // Adjust path if necessary
      92 |                 .send(mockVendorData)
    > 93 |                 .expect(201); // Expect successful creation status code
         |                  ^
      94 |             console.log(res.body)
      95 |             expect(res.body.success).toHaveProperty('name', mockVendorData.name); // Check name in response
      96 |             expect(res.body.success).toHaveProperty('email', mockVendorData.email);

      at source/__test__/controllers/AdminController.test.ts:93:18
      at source/__test__/controllers/AdminController.test.ts:8:71
      at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (source/__test__/controllers/AdminController.test.ts:4:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (source/__test__/controllers/AdminController.test.ts:76:60)
      ----
      at Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
      at node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:308:13
      at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
      at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
      at Server.localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)

I tried importing the generateSalt function from the ../../utilities.js file and using jest.spyOn to mock it. I provided a mock implementation that always returns a string value for the salt.
I expected the test to pass and the mocked generateSalt function to be called once during the execution of the CreateVendor function. However, the test fails.

Where do Vendor, generateSalt, etc come from? This is not shown and is very relevant. If they are imports, you have to use jest.mock at top level to mock the modules. "This concise statement" - is this generated text? AI content is banned on SO for a good reason

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your first error was

Property generateSalt does not exist in the provided object

which means that your program wanted to refer to generateSalt but it did not exist. As you pointed out, you imported generateSalt from ../../utilities.js and, despite of that, your test still failed.
However, if you look at the error message you shared, it's no longer complaining about generateSalt not existing, instead, it successfully executed generateSalt and now it fails at
                .post('/admin/vendor') // Adjust path if necessary
                .send(mockVendorData)
                .expect(201); // Expect successful creation status code

This error tells you that the vendor was not successfully created. Since the error status if 404 instead of 201, it's highly probable that your URL is wrong.
